# Appending data on google sheet using php works on local host but doesn't on Cpanel

Tags: php, html, api, google-sheets

I was able to get my code to append data submitted by a form to a google sheets document using the Google API

```
<?php
    require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

    $client = new \Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName('php to sheets');
    $client->setScopes([\Google_Service_Sheets::SPREADSHEETS]);
    $client->setAccessType('offline');
    $client->setAuthConfig(__DIR__ . '/credentials.json');

    $service = new Google_Service_Sheets($client);
    $spreadsheetId = "1QB_xjhw18b7J7WG0BSYkjf9RgqqgZspz_KYmBqD9yS4";

    if (!empty($_POST)){
        echo $_POST['name'];

        $range = "congress";
        $values = [
            [$_POST['name'] , $_POST['rating'] , $_POST['notes'] ],
        ];

        $body = new Google_Service_Sheets_ValueRange([
            'values' => $values
        ]);

        $params = [
            'valueInputOption' => 'RAW'
        ];

        $insert = [
            "insertDataOption" => "INSERT_ROWS"
        ];

        $result = $service->spreadsheets_values->append(
            $spreadsheetId,
            $range,
            $body,
            $params,
            $insert
        );

        header("Location: Thanks.html");
    }
?>
```

once I uploaded the project folder the page got stuck on the file and wouldn't update the google sheet

Comment: Have you tried using `var_dump` on the `$result` to see what you get in production? Also, what do you mean by `page got stuck on the file`?

Comment: I didn't try the var_dump, might as well give it a shot. I mean it didn't forward to the page i had in the header and stayed on the php page

Comment: When using var_dump it returns a NULL

Comment: What do you get in your local development environment? Is it also null there?

Comment: Actually if the Var_dump is placed after the declaration of $result it won't run at all, same goes for any echo after the statement 

but it runs everything until you get to the live where you declare the $result

Comment: Are you sure your credentials are valid for the host you want to run the script at? Is your host among the valid redirect urls for the consent screen?